# What is the value of $|A'|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A$ and $B$ are subsets of universal set. 
>   $3$ elements of $A$ and $5$ elements of $B$ are not elements of the set $A \cap B$. Moreover $|A \cup B| = 16$ and $|\mathbb U| = 24$.
>   What is the value of $|A'|$?

I currently don't have any idea about the question. Might I get your hints?

Comment: I didn't get what the question wants.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: I've already drawn it.

Comment: I guess $A'$ is the complement of $A $ (elements of $\mathbb U $ not in $A $ ) and you are asked how many elements are in it. I've seen the notation $A'$ and also $A^C $.

Comment: "*I didn't get what the question wants.*"  Let's give it flavor then.  Let $U$ be the set of students in our class.  Let $A$ be the set of people who play piano.  Let $B$ be the set of people who play violin.  We are told how many students play piano but not violin (3), we are told how many play violin but not piano (5), we are told how many play at least one of piano or violin (16), and we are told how many are in the class alltogether (24).  We are asked how many students don't play piano at all (possibly playing violin only or playing neither).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3+5+|A\cap B|=16,$$
which gives $|A\cap B|=8.$

Thus, $$|A|=3+8=11$$ and
$$|A'|=24-11=13.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that the universal set is the disjoint union of $A$ , the set of elements of $B$ which are not elements of $A\cap B$ and the complement of $A\cup B$:
$$|\mathbb{U}|=|A|+|B\setminus(A\cap B)|+(|\mathbb{U}|-|A\cup B)|).$$
Therefore
$$|A|'=|\mathbb{U}|-|A|=|B\setminus(A\cap B)|+(|\mathbb{U}|-|A\cup B)|).$$

P.S.  The information "3 elements of $A$ are not elements of $A\cap B$" is not necessary to evaluate $|A|'$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$|A'| = |\mathbb{U}|-|A\cup B| + |B-A| = 24 - 16 + 5 = 13$$